# Can't sign in to admin page magento

Tags: magento

I can't login to admin page in magento via chrome, ie, opera. I can do this only via mozilla. I just redirects to the login page without errors

```
`(ver. 1.8.1.0)`
```

[image]
Thanks!

```
a:5:{i:0;s:113:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Magecom_Getaquote_setup' for key 'PRIMARY'";i:1;s:1736:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Resource.php(133): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('core_resource', Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(423): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Resource->setDbVersion('Magecom_Getaquo...', '0.1.0')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('0.1.0')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}";s:3:"url";s:90:"/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/advanced/key/2d59480187e040546c3881179bf1eddb/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}


a:5:{i:0;s:113:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Magecom_Getaquote_setup' for key 'PRIMARY'";i:1;s:1736:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Resource.php(133): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('core_resource', Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(423): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Resource->setDbVersion('Magecom_Getaquo...', '0.1.0')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('0.1.0')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\www\index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}";s:3:"url";s:87:"/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/admin/key/2d59480187e040546c3881179bf1eddb/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

P.S. I am new in magento

Comment: Turn on network monitoring in the browser (F12 in chrome), and look at the log files on the server in $magento_dir/var/log and maybe $magento_dir/var/report to obtain more information.

Comment: I am will add logs now.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_fix_login_for_admin_on_local_install#dokuwiki__top
Check this link it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit varien.php
This is the path: app->code->core->mage->core->model->session->abstract->varien.php

```
    // session cookie params

 <pre>$cookieParams = array( 
   'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
    //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
    //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);</pre>
```

Comment: i facing also same issue but currently my site is down have any idea?